# Atlassian JIRA Java library attach file to task immediately upon creation

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-java-api

Working with Atlassian Java API. Making 2 steps:

**1. Creating issue**

```
        IssueType it = new IssueType(jiraServerUri, ticket.getTypeId(),
                ticket.getTypeName(), false, ticket.getTypeName(), null);
        issueBuilder.setIssueType(it);

        IssueInput issueInput = issueBuilder.build();

        Promise<BasicIssue> reply = issueRestClient.createIssue(issueInput);
        BasicIssue issue = reply.claim();
        LOG.debug("CREATED TICKET:/" + issue.getKey() + "/" + issue + "/");
```

**2. Attaching files**

```
        com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue issueWithAttachment = issueRestClient.getIssue(key).claim();

        if (attachments != null && ! attachments.isEmpty()) {
            attachments.forEach((name, contents) -> {
                try {
                    String attUrl = issueWithAttachment.getAttachmentsUri().toString();
                    LOG.info("TEMP_ATTACH_LOG: Original attachment url: " + attUrl);

                    issueRestClient.addAttachment(
                            new URI(attUrl),
                                new ByteArrayInputStream(contents.getBytes(ENCODING_DEFAULT)),
                                name + TXT_POSTFIX_DEFAULT)
                            .claim();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | URISyntaxException e) {
                    LOG.error("TEMP_ATTACH_LOG Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
        return key;
```

, where `key` is `issue.getKey()` from 1st step.

So it works fine, but not in my case for some reasons (beyond the discussion of this issue).

So, question is - can I do both in just one step? I mean, fill all the issue info (title, body, **attachments** etc) in a single step and submit it to jira server with one command (like `claim()` I suppose...).

Comment: Step 1 you are using BasicIssue but step 2 you are using com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue. Why?

Comment: Well because ```issueRestClient.getIssue()``` returns this type.